# PIG UDF's in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-pig, udf, apache-hive

Apologies for no code on this as this is a Generic Question -

Can PIG UDF's be consumed from Hive? Specifically can the PIG Apache DataFu (http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/) UDF'S be used in HIVE?

I saw a Jira about using HIVE UDF's in PIG - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3294

Question is can we do this other way around?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: What UDF from DataFu are you wanting to use?

Comment: The Statistics ones -  median, quantiles, variance etc.. I just verified that most of these are available in Hive except PageRank.